# Is there a way to undo `git push --force origin master`?

Tags: git, github, git-revert

I created a repository, added some commits, pushed to GitHub.

Later, I created a new project, new local git repository and I wanted to commit new files from new repository to the old repository on GitHub. So I executed:
`git push --force origin master` but this command removed all previous commits from the repository on GitHub.

Is there a way turning back? How to make it properly next time?

Comment: To "make it properly next time", don't use `--force`.

Comment: Push the old master reference again. And the proper way would be to never force push except when you know *exactly* what you are doing. You could also use the `--force-with-lease` option.